# React-Router v4 (List / ListItem, Routes, Animations)

Tags: reactjs, animation, shared-element-transition, react-router-v4

I just ran into a problem with react router v4, maybe it's not a big deal, but I don't know how to handle this the right way.
It should look something like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={List}>
     <Route path="/listitem/:id" component={ListItem} />
</Route>
```

If I am now on the ("/" - List)-page I want to see **all** the ListItems from the different ("/listitem/:id" - ListItem)-pages. *(with less informations but this should be a simple css-problem)*
As soon as I click at one, I want to turn that one fullscreen (animations and stuff... but that's not the problem here) and the route should change, unsurprisingly :-).
If I am now on one specific ListItem and trigger history.goBack(), I want to animate that Item back into the List and the route should change back to "/".

*Additional (maybe optional) thought: If I visite the site initially at a "/listitem/:id"-page and click on a Link to the "(/" - List)-page, there shouldn't be any animation of the ListItem.*

I guess it's a basic problem for react-router, but I actually don't know right now how to implement this properly.
I don't know if it makes any difference, but I am using Redux aswell.
I hope, someone can help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be best handled with state in the Parent component. For example:

`this.state = {
  fullscreen: false,
  idOpened: null
}`

Once you click on the child component (the list item), you set a callback that sends the ID to the parent which then triggers the fullscreen-mode. This way you won't need to use the history API and the visitors won't have to wait for page loads (except for the initial one).

It'll also make it easy to not trigger any animations when clicking on another list item.